# How to specify ionic build folder in CLI

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a ionic app and to build the project in android I use the command

> ionic build android

It works fine and i'm able to build the project.

However if I want to specify an external folder in the path like...

> ionic d:\Projects\mobile build android

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this.  If you have an `ionic:build` npm script defined it will call that to do the build.

```
"scripts":{
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build android --release --prod  --wwwDir www --buildDir build"
}
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic/app-scripts  - Please can you comment how this is to use and what it will do?

Comment: This was from a very long time ago, and a lot has changed.  I would suggest you start fresh.

Comment: this answer was right at some point but unfortunately Ionic stopped using app-scripts pattern a while back

Answer (score -5):

For achieving your goal there is one more way. Instead of passing the path in the ionic commands ( Which is not a valid command ), you can first reach to the path where you want to build ionic application using cd command.

In your case it would be first go to d drive by using

d:

then

cd \Projects\mobile.

After this you can run command

ionic build android

Comment: This doesn't make sense.